# Soft delete best practices (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, soft-delete

**Problem**

In a web application dealing with products and orders, I want to maintain information and relationships between former employees (users) and the orders they handled. I want to maintain information and relationships between obsolete products and orders which include these products.

However I want employees to be able to de-clutter the administration interfaces, such as removing former employees, obsolete products, obsolete product groups etc.

I'm thinking of implementing soft-deletion. So, how does one usually do this?

**My immediate thoughts**

My first thought is to stick a "`flag_softdeleted` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0" column in every table of objects that should be soft deletable. Or maybe use a timestamp instead?

Then, I provide a "Show deleted" or "Undelete" button in each relevant GUI. Clicking this button you will include soft-deleted records in the result. Each deleted record has a "Restore" button. Does this make sense?

Your thoughts?

Also, I'd appreciate any links to relevant resources.

Comment: Depending on the size of your Employee/Products tables, it may be better to create a separate table with the IDs of your Soft-Deleted items.

Comment: timestamp is always useful. however, you can use whatever you want - it's not THAT big deal to make a question of

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's how I do it.  I have a `is_deleted` field which defaults to 0.  Then queries just check `WHERE is_deleted = 0`.

I try to stay away from any hard-deletes as much as possible.  They are necessary sometimes, but I make that an admin-only feature.  That way we can hard-delete, but users can't...

**Edit:** In fact, you could use this to have multiple "layers" of soft-deletion in your app.  So each could be a code:

- `0` -> Not Deleted
- `1` -> Soft Deleted, shows up in lists of deleted items for management users
- `2` -> Soft Deleted, does not show up for any user except admin users
- `3` -> Only shows up for developers.

Having the other 2 levels will still allow managers and admins to clean up the deleted lists if they get too long.  And since the front-end code just checks for `is_deleted = 0`, it's transparent to the frontend...

Comment: We do a tiered hierarchy for our internal CRM. We also use a trigger to add a deleted entry to a backup table. This comes in handy if someone ever needs to audit an admin level account or if an admin level user accidentally deletes the wrong record.

Comment: ENUM would probably be better than 0,1,2,4. ENUM would be self documenting, and just as performing.

Comment: Beware to not be beaten with a uniq column: Your "deleted" elements will still hold a value in your uniq column, that may not be what you want. But you may set this colonne to NULL while soft deleting the raw to avoid conflicts...

Comment: what if the normal user soft deletes a parent record that has children records. In such case parent record and all its children will be hidden to normal users . That is exactly same like cascade delete problem. So my question is that how to check referential integrity before soft deleting the parent records ?

Comment: also you can use an extra field (or replace this one) as datetime/timestamp to know when the row was "deleted"

Answer (score 11):

Using soft-deletes is a common thing to implement, and they are dead useful for lots of things, like:

- Saving a user's data when they deleted something
- Saving your own data when you delete something
- Keep a track record of what really happened (a kind of audit)
- etcetera

There is one thing I want to point out that almost everyone miss, and it always comes back to bite you in the rear piece. The users of your application does not have the same understanding of a *delete* as you have.

There are different *degrees* of deletions. The typical user deletes stuff when (s)he

- Made a misstake and want to remove the bad data
- Doesn't want to see something on the screen anymore

The problem is that if you don't record the *intention* of the delete, your application cannot distinguish between erronous data (that should never have been created) and historically correct data.

Have a look at the following data:

```
PRICES | item | price | deleted |
       +------+-------+---------+
       |   A  |  101  |    1    |
       |   B  |  110  |    1    |
       |   C  |  120  |    0    |
       +------+-------+---------+
```

Some user doesn't want to show the price of item B, since they don't sell that item anymore. So he deletes it. Another user created a price for item A by misstake, so he deleted it and created the price for item C, as intended. Now, can you show me a list of the prices for all products? No, because either you have to display potentially erronous data (A), or you have to exclude all but current prices (C).

Of course the above can be dealt with in any number of ways. My point is that **YOU** need to be very clear with what **YOU** mean by a delete, and make sure that there is no way for the users to missunderstand it. One way would be to force the user to make a choice (hide/delete).

Answer (score 6):

If I had existing code that hits that table, I would add the column and change the name of the table. Then I would create a view with the same name as the current table which selects only the active records.  That way none of the existing code woudl break and you could have the soft delete column. If you want to see the deleted record, you select from the base table, otherwise you use the view.

Comment: Although short, I would accept this solution instead. This in principle applies to real production databases and is DEFINITELY the way to go. No one would want to have a deleted column and be prone to just forgetting adding the condition "where deleted=0" in one of the many queries that will be used in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I've always just used a *deleted* column as you mentioned.  There's really not much more to it than that. Instead of deleting the record, just set the *deleted* field to true.

Some components I build allow the user to view all deleted records and restore them, others just display all records where *deleted* = 0

Answer (score 1):

Your idea does make sense and is used frequently in production but, to implement it you will need to update quite a bit of code to account for the new field. Another option could be to archive (move) the "soft-deleted" records to a separate table or database. This is done frequently as well and makes the issue one of maintenance rather than (re)programming. (You could have a table trigger react to the delete to archive the deleted record.)

I would do the archiving to avoid a major update to production code. But if you want to use deleted-flag field, use it as a timestamp to give you additional useful info beyond a boolean. (Null = not deleted.) You might also want to add a DeletedBy field to track the user responsible for deleting the record. Using two fields gives you a lot of info tells you who deleted what and when. (The two extra field solution is also something that can be done in an archive table/database.)

Answer (score 0):

The most common scenario I've come across is what you describe, a `tinyint` or even `bit` representing a status of `IsActive` or `IsDeleted`.  Depending on whether this is considered "business" or "persistence" data it may be baked into the application/domain logic as transparently as possible, such as directly in stored procedures and not known to the application code.  But it sounds like this is legitimate business information for your needs so would need to be known throughout the code.  (So users can view deleted records, as you suggest.)

Another approach I've seen is to use a combination of two timestamps to show a "window" of activity for a given record.  It's a little more code to maintain it, but the benefit is that something can be scheduled to soft-delete itself at a pre-determined time.  Limited-time products can be set that way when they're created, for example.  (To make a record active indefinitely one could use a max value (or just some absurdly distant future date) or just have the end date be `null` if you're ok with that.)

Then of course there's further consideration of things being deleted/undeleted from time to time and tracking some kind of audit for that.  The flag approach knows only the current status, the timestamp approach knows only the most recent window.  But anything as complex as an audit trail should definitely be stored separately than the records in question.

Comment: There's BIT in MySQL?? I've always used TINYINT. ***mind blown*** What's the difference between using BIT and TINYINT for a boolean field?

Comment: @arex1337: `bit` actually used to be a synonym for `tinyint` in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html  You're probably better off with `tinyint`, but don't quote me on that.  In some other databases one key difference is that `bit` can't be indexed, or handles `null` differently (or not at all), etc.  But I don't have enough direct knowledge of the data types for MySQL to really be an authority on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would use a **bin** table in which to move all the records deleted from the other tables. The main problem with the delete flag is that with linked tables you will definitely run into a double key error when trying to insert a new record.

The **bin** table could have a structure like this:

```
id, table_name, data, date_time, user
```

Where

- *id* is the primary key with auto increment
- *table_name* is the name of the table from which the record was deleted
- *data contains* the record in JSON format with name and value of all fields
- *date_time* is the date and time of the deletion
- *user* is the identifier of the user (if the system provides for it) who performed the operation

this method will not only save you from checking the delete flag at each query (immagine the ones with many joins), but will allow you to have only the really necessary data in the tables, facilitating any searches and corrections using SQL client programs