# SQL query output to SQL query

Tags: mysql, terminal, putty

How is it possible to have the result of an sql query saved as another sql query, so that somewhere down the line , if a delete is made, it could be reverted back to the old data?

I was looking into making a system call. Something like this

```
system (mysql -uuser-ppassword -Ddatabase < select.sql > backup.sql
```

where select.sql is the intial query, and backup.sql is the final query. 
When i execute it, just get a datadump in backup.sql

Please Help

Comment: you need to use mysqldump. mysql does not output data in an 'sql' syntax. it'll output text-based tables.

Comment: For this purpose, people have invented a soft-delete.

Comment: Check how [soft-delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020568/soft-delete-best-practices-php-mysql) is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQLyog (http://www.webyog.com/) to export a table as a series of insert statements. This should do what you want, although I'm not totally sure that it can export the results of a select statement with a where clause. It will allow you to choose which columns to export.