# Want to Perform soft deletion of data

Tags: java

I am creating one actor object and storing that actor object inside databases and what ever object i am creating it is also populated on drop down list , Now my requirement is that I want to delete this actor object but it should delete temporary from database  means deletion operation should perform but original object reference should still remain in databases  so in future i can retrieve those data,  but once You delete the object it should not available in drop-down list .

Finally I want to Tell Can Any One Provide Java Code To Perform Soft-Deletion of Data, so that i can take some help

Comment: create another field in your database .when you delete set it to false .

Comment: Please read the "how to ask a question" section of the FAQ. In particular, clear, readable questions which show some effort to solve the problem are welcome.

Comment: You can also maintain soft deletion in a separate table and fetch drop-down list data as a result of join on 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Java question but just to point you in the right direction, this is more related to your Database design.

The simplest way to do this is to add a new column in your `actor` table.

Something like `actor.is_deleted` or `actor.is_active`.

**EDIT**: Here is a [good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020568/soft-delete-best-practices-php-mysql) about it.

Comment: Can AnyOne Give one referance

Answer (score 0):

**

> You can add the a column in the DB called "IsDeleted" with the type
>   Boolean or char(1). values can be True or false(Y or N). while
>   fetching the data from the database fetch it if it is (Y)false and
>   populate it to the drop down.

**